# PowerShell | Color Results from PSCustomObject

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to color the values depending on the value of the bool being True=green and False=Red.
I tried doing that in another foreach loop which did not work no matter what.
How would I best go about this?

My Code:

```
while($true){
    $UserID = Read-Host -Prompt 'UserID'
    
    $GroupNames = @("WHfB","LongName345","Some-Group2","Group","Example123","Another-One21")
    
    $Prompt = 'net user '+$UserID+' /domain'
    $Result = cmd.exe /c $Prompt
    
    echo "`n`nTrue  =`tMember of Group;`nFalse =`tNO Member of Group;`n`n"
    
    $Table = foreach ($item in $GroupNames){
        [PSCustomObject]@{
            GroupName = $item
            IsMember = [bool]($Result -match $item)
        }
    }
    $Table | Format-Table
    pause
}
```

Result right know:

```
True  = Member of Group;
False = No Member of Group;



GroupName             IsMember
---------             --------
WHfB                      True
LongName345               True
Some-Group2               True
Group                     True
Example123                True
Another-One21             True
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a hashtable that holds the [ANSI escape codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code) for green and red, then in your code you can use the bool from that `-match` comparison to inject the sequences before the property values:

```bash
$colors = @{
    $false = "$([char] 27)[91m" # Red
    $true  = "$([char] 27)[32m" # Green
    reset  = "$([char] 27)[0m"
}

while ($true) {
    # same code as before here..

    $Table = foreach ($item in $GroupNames) {
        $isMember = [bool]($Result -match $item)
        [PSCustomObject]@{
            GroupName = $colors[$isMember] + $item + $colors['reset']
            IsMember  = $isMember
        }
    }
    $Table | Format-Table
    pause
}
```

If using **pwsh7.2+** you can use [`$PSStyle`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_ansi_terminals?view=powershell-7.4) instead, making it much simpler:

```bash
$colors = @{
    $false = $PSStyle.Foreground.Red
    $true  = $PSStyle.Foreground.Green
    reset  = $PSStyle.Reset
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! But how would I go about returning the color to white after the first loop of the script? Right now it also changes the color of the text of the second loop. I tried it with `IsMember  = $isMember+"$([char] 27)[46m"` But I have no clue which values are which color and it does not seem to work that way anyways.

Comment: @J0nsan my bad. i missed the reset sequence after coloring. pls try with the edit

Comment: Thanks again. I have another question about that: How can I reset the color only after the loop? In your original solution the true or false is colored as well which I quite like. If I try `IsMember  = $isMember + $colors['reset']` it won't work because it is a bool/int not a string. Or is there some way to reset all text color at the beginning of the while loop so UserID: won't be colored as well?

Comment: @J0nsan could you send me a screenshot of how you see it as I'm not sure I understand what you mean, this is how I see it: https://i.imgur.com/8MWQ0HT.png coloring seems fine

Comment: For me it looks like this, because I left out `$colors['reset']` [https://imgur.com/a/Yx5KMBe](https://imgur.com/a/Yx5KMBe) Reason being that I would like True and False to be colored as well as in the Screenshot. But this then has the unintened effect of "Press Enter to continue...:" and UserID of the next loop being colored green or red as well.

Comment: @J0nsan gotcha. but it should be good now right? as long as you use the `reset` one

Comment: Not quite, if I use reset then true/False won't be colored. I would like both values GroupName and IsMeber to be colored in a way it wont color everything after the table as well. How would I manage that?

Comment: @J0nsan you should do the same for `IsMember`: `$colors[$isMember] + $IsMember + $colors['reset']`